# HTTPURLConnection port number assignment

Tags: java, sockets, port, httpurlconnection

I was working with HTTPURLConnection and wondered how the port issues handled ? I mean the class uses sockets under the hood but how the client socket's port number is assigned internally? Any ideas ?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't. It is left entirely up to the operating system.

Comment: But you are not able to assign it if you don't pass port number via the URL. Can you please a bit elaborate your statement , for example in Unix, if possible ?

Comment: You aren't able to assign it anyway. The port number in the URL is the *target* port. The port number you asked about is the *local* port. You can't control it. You don't need to control it. There isn't a problem here to solve.

Comment: I see your point. I don't need to know it, yes. But I just wanted to know under the hood stuff. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a socket you have to take into account whether you want to open a server-socket or a client-socket.

A server-socket is opend and sits there waiting for an incoming request to start a "conversation". So it needs a port-number that is known to the client. For this reason several services have "well-known ports" like HTTP is port 80 etc.

A client-socket is created an starts with contacting a server-socket. In this case the server does not need to know the clients port-number in advance - it will receive it with the first incoming request. So when opening a client-socket the operating system will just choose a random port from a list of unused ports (look up "ephemeral port") and often close it once the conversation is finished.

The situation is similar to ip-adresses: the client needs to know the servers ip-address to contact it but the server does not need to know each clients ip-address.

Comment: Sure. It doesn't have to know. Thanks for the exp. though. One extra reminder note is - it ( socket/port ) should be released from the code to let the underlying os close it. The handle's not gonna be closed otherwise when the conversation has just finished ( if you didn't mean it by saying "closing conversation" ).

Comment: @zgulser One of closing the input stream or calling `disconnect()` should close the socket.